# Comparing N Objects In A Complex Structure C#

Tags: c#

I have a set of instances of the `Data` class that I want to compare. 
Each instance has an unknown number of items in it's `Files` property.

I want to compare each instance of `Data` to the others and set `FoundDifference` to `true` if a version difference is found between two files with the same `Name` value.

Is there a simple algorithm to accomplish this?

Here is a sample setup of how the objects might look.
In this example you'd want everything except for f1, f21, and f31 to set the FoundDifference to true

```
class Data
{
    public string DC { get; set; }
    public List<File> Files { get; set; }

}

class File
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Version { get; set; }
    public bool FoundDifference { get; set; }

}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Data d1 = new Data();
        d1.DC = "DC1";

        File f1 = new File();
        f1.Name = "File1";
        f1.Version = "1";
        d1.Files.Add(f1);

        File f2 = new File();
        f2.Name = "File2";
        f2.Version = "1";
        d1.Files.Add(f2);

        File f3 = new File();
        f3.Name = "File3";
        f3.Version = "1";
        d1.Files.Add(f3);

        //Another
        Data d2 = new Data();
        d2.DC = "DC2";

        File f21 = new File();
        f21.Name = "File1";
        f21.Version = "1";
        d2.Files.Add(f21);

        File f22 = new File();
        f22.Name = "File2";
        f22.Version = "2";
        d2.Files.Add(f22);

        File f23 = new File();
        f23.Name = "File3";
        f23.Version = "1";
        d2.Files.Add(f23);

        //Another
        Data d3 = new Data();
        d3.DC = "DC3";

        File f31 = new File();
        f31.Name = "File1";
        f31.Version = "1";
        d3.Files.Add(f31);

        File f32 = new File();
        f32.Name = "File2";
        f32.Version = "2";
        d3.Files.Add(f32);

        File f33 = new File();
        f33.Name = "File3";
        f33.Version = "5";
        d3.Files.Add(f33);


        //How Can I change All Files FoundDifference prop to true if FileName is the same and a difference is in Version is found??

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: We need a little clarification here - would you be comparing the files in d1 to the files in d2 and d3, or each file in d1 to the other files in d1, etc.?

Comment: @SamW I am Comparing Across d1, d2,d3, dn not inside a given dn

Comment: So for the example you'd want everything except for `f1`, `f21`, and `f31` to set the  `FoundDifference` to true?  If not can you explain exactly which ones should be set and why?

Comment: @juharr Yes exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd handle that by using a `Dictionary<string, List<File>>` to keep track of the files from each `Data` like this.  First iterate all the files in all the datas then lookup the file name in the dictionary and if not found create a new list and add it.  Then check if that list has any files with a different version.  If one is found set all the flags and finally add the file to the list.

```
public void SetDifferences(IEnumerable<Data> datas)
{
    var fileLookup = new Dictionary<string, List<File>>();
    foreach(var file in datas.SelectMany(d => d.Files))
    {
        if(!fileLookup.TryGetValue(file.Name, out var fileList))
        {
            fileList = new List<File>();
            fileLookup.Add(file.Name, fileList);
        }

        if(fileList.Any(f => f.Version != file.Version))
        {
            foreach(var other in fileList)
            {
                other.FoundDifference = true;
            }

            file.FoundDifference = true;
        }

        fileList.Add(file);
    }
}
```

Comment: Works Great Very Cool Thank You